# Como validar um spinner?

Tags: android

Boa tarde. Estou fazendo um  aplicação Android que possui um formulário, e nesse formulário existem *spinners* e campos de texto de resposta. Alguém pode me ajudar como que eu verifico se o *spinner* foi selecionado?

Answer (score 1):

É meio braçal, mas é uma solução que funciona bem pra mim.

Adicione um item em branco no spinner, com um texto padrão, exemplo, "Selecione uma opção". Depois trate o evento setOnItemSelectedListener do spinner e guarde a posição selecionada. Se for diferente da inicial do spinner, o usuário selecionou algo.

```
spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                mSpinnerPos = position;
            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

            }
        });
```

Se alguém tiver alguma dica para incrementar a solução e deixá-la menos braçal agradeço.

Comment: Boa tarde! muito obrigado pela sugestão, eu não estou utilizando o listener, pois ele fica sempre ativo na execução da chamada, pra evitar o uso de memoria eu acabei fazendo somente a chamada para conferir. Mais a sua solução é bem interessante tbm, tem uma condição que eu vou usar.

Answer (score 1):

Acabei fazendo dessa forma braçal pra resolver, dessa forma ela ja disconsidera o spinner null, funcionou. Se houver sugestão melhor agradeço.

```
boolean validaConfere = false;
if (spnConheceAbrigo.getSelectedItem().toString().equals("Sim")){
    if (listaAbrigoSolicitacao.size() == 0){
        validaConfere = false;
        imprimirAlertaAbrigos();
    }else {
        validaConfere = true;
    }
}
else if (spnConheceAbrigo.getSelectedItem().toString().equals("Não")){

    if (listaAbrigoSolicitacao.size() == 0){
        validaConfere = true;
    }else {
        listaAbrigoSolicitacao.clear();
        cbOcoArvore.setChecked(false);
        cbCaverna.setChecked(false);
        cbForroCasa.setChecked(false);
        cbTuneuTrem.setChecked(false);
        cbBueiro.setChecked(false);
        cbCasaVelha.setChecked(false);
        validaConfere = true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Olá,

Então considerando que o seu Spinner terá um valor padrão *null*, uma forma mais simples de validá-lo seria assim:

```
String valor = null;

if(spinnerNome != null && spinnerNome.getSelectedItem() !=null ) {
   valor = (String) spinnerNome.getSelectedItem();
} else  { 
    //Spinner vazio
}
```

Também tem mais exemplos nesta documentação do [Android](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/spinner.html).